# Filament Admin Edit do an Action on setting data

Tags: laravel

So I have a filament admin panel with many many tables in the db. I generated a resource for listing the Orders. One of the item is a boolean, which is set to false by default. Where can I add an extra action, that runs when one of the admin sets that boolean record to true?

```
<?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         */
    
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('email');
                $table->string('tel');
                $table->integer('pax');
                $table->string('route');
                $table->string('pid');
                $table->string('price');
                $table->boolean('isPaid');
                $table->timestamps();   
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         */
        public function down(): void
        {
            //
        }
    };
```

Migration file - isPaid Boolean is the one.

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\OrderResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Resources\OrderResource\RelationManagers;
use App\Models\Order;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Resources\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Resources\Table;
use Filament\Tables;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class OrderResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Order::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-collection';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                    ->email()
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('tel')
                    ->tel()
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('pax')
                    ->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('route')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('pid')
                    ->required()
                    ->disabled()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('price')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\Toggle::make('isPaid')
                    ->required(),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('tel'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('pax'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('route'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('pid'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('price'),
                Tables\Columns\IconColumn::make('isPaid')
                    ->boolean(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime(),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
    
    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
    
    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListOrders::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateOrder::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditOrder::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }    
}
```

And I have this generated Resource

So my question is: how can I add an extra action to run when isPaid boolean is modified?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterStateUpdated()` method on **Toggle** field, like below,

```
Toggle::make('isPaid')->afterStateUpdated(function($state){
    //$state contains field value
})
```

Yoh might want to check **Field component utility injection** and **Field Lifecycle** in the **Advanced Form section** inside **Form Builder** in yhe docs.

[Filament php v3 Advanced Form](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/advanced)